# SQLPackage and DB on Azure

Tags: sqlpackage

I am running sqlpackage from commandline:

```
sqlpackage.exe /action:Extract  /TargetFile:"C:\file.dacpac" /sourceDatabasename:dbsorgente  /sourceservername:dummy.database.windows.net  /p:ExtractAllTableData=True
```

and I get error:
[Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server]

The db is on Azure and from Sql Management STudio I can successfully connect to it.
Can you help me ?

Comment: I am using Sql Autentication.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify also `/SourceUser:` and `/SourcePassword:` in your command, otherwise it will use Windows login to authenticate to source server.

So your command should look like:

```
sqlpackage.exe /action:Extract  /TargetFile:"C:\file.dacpac" /sourceDatabasename:dbsorgente  /sourceservername:dummy.database.windows.net  /sourceuser=yourUser /sourcePassword=yourPassword /p:ExtractAllTableData=True
```